# Freezing Ubuntu with threadripper 3990x

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, threadripper

I am having issues with Ubuntu 19. The whole computer is freezing often. The timing of freezing is happening with or without CPU load. I am using the Threadripper 3990x. So basically I just wanna check if other people also have this problem, and what are tips in general to prevent such.

Thanks!

Comment: could you run `dstat` in terminal to see what kind of load is happening when freezes occur?
Or maybe because of your 64core (!) CPU electricity from power station can not flow fast enough to satisfy such powerful CPU :D :)

Comment: Yeah, it also happened when there is no load. And I provided a 1kW power supply. So  that should not be an issue given that the TDP is at 280 Watts. Maybe there is an option to check after next reboot what the issue was?

Comment: Do you have any way to see CPU temperature? Try `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` it's temperature *100. See if system is overheating.